# Stop form from redirecting on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm very aware that this question has been asked several times but I have tried at least 6 solutions and it has not worked. I'm collecting data to send to a google form but on form submission the browser redirects to a success page. I'd like for it to all happen using AJAX but my code isn't working.

HTML:

```
<form  id="userinfo" method="get" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxx/exec" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="formname" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="formemail" placeholder="Email">placeholder="Game Days">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="upload_data"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#userinfo").submit(function(e) {

        var urll = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxx/exec"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: urll,
               data: $("#userinfo").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   alert(data); // show response from the php script.
               }
             });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
```

Comment: first, you should prevent the default action on the first line so that if an error occurs that stops the processing of javascript the regular sumbit doens't occur because it has already been prevented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery Form Plugin](https://jquery-form.github.io/form/) to send the form without doing a submit.

Your code should look kinda like this:

```
$("#userInfo").ajaxSubmit({
   success: function(data)
   {
       alert(data); // show response from the php script.
   }
});
```